# Нужны ли такие знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

***Вот мы пришли к ней(,) и видим(:) она сидит на диване...***

Ставятся ли знаки препинания (в скобках)?

Answer (score 1):

Вот мы пришли к ней и видим: она сидит на диване..

Это однородные сказуемые, связанные одиночным союзом И, запятая не нужна.

Двоеточие обозначает изъяснительные отношения (что видим).

Comment: спасибо большое!!!